# Invest columns in mobile devices

Tags: wordpress

Hello everyone and thanks for your help. I am using a wordpress theme using WPBakery (visual Composer). I need to know how I can invert the columns for mobile devices using an Extra class name.
To be clear, I need that in mobiles you see the image first and then the text.[See attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbAzS.png)

Comment: So if you've already added a class to the columns, now find where you can add custom CSS, should be in the customization somewhere. Then search on google for media queries - that should lead you in the right direction. Using media queries you'll be able to have something in the effect of 'if screensize is < x and also > y then show columns like this'. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanksm you `re the best